# Strange behaviour with vector operations in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, plot, operations

I have a formula

```
F = (-k.^(3/2) .* sqrt(4 .* c .* x + k) + 2 .* x .* k .* c + k.^2) / (2 .* c)
```

and i'm trying to plot F against a range of values of c for a constant x and k value like so:

```
x = 0.01;
c = 10000:10000:100000;
k = 100000;
F = (-k.^(3/2) .* sqrt(4 .* c .* x + k) + 2 .* x .* k .* c + k.^2) / (2 .* c)
```

At this point I assumed matlab would give me a vector with the same size as c but it just prints:

```
F =

   47.1563
```

Plotting F against a range of k values for constant c and x works fine, but the above does not.

Can anybody explain this for me?

Comment: The division. you are using matrix division, you forgot that small point you put in themultiplocations in the division!! / -> ./

Comment: I am guessing right now but i think you are changing a `vec(a)=b*vec(c)` into `b=vec(a)/vec(c)` so you get a scalar value. Try to do `(...).*(2.*C).^(-1)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use element wise division `./`, similar to `.*`

```
F = (-k.^(3/2) .* sqrt(4 .* c .* x + k) + 2 .* x .* k .* c + k.^2) ./ (2 .* c)
```

The `/` is used for right-matrix division: `A/B` is equivalent to `mrdivide(A,B)`,which solves the system of (linear) equations `x*B = A` for `x`, whereas `./` is just element wise division.

Comment: +1 but you should add an explanation of why `/` gives a single value back

Comment: Good point. `/` is  right-matrix division. `A/B` is equivalent to `mrdivide(A,B)`,which solves the system of (linear) equations x*B = A for x.

Comment: I took the liberty of moving your explanation into the solution. The question ends with "Can anyone explain this to me" so I think the correct solution should have an explanation and not just correct the error.